# Jquery favorite function call api with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django-templates

I'm trying to create a favorite function in my django template that let user click on the icon and it will call to an api i made to send add and remove that favorite item from user data.

[image: favorite and unfavorite button]

Currently how it work is if user click on the icon(favorite or unfavorite) it will call to an api that handle add favorite or remove favorite, and also it will replace the DOM of that  tag with the opposite (for example if i click on favorite then the entire  tag of it will be replace with  tag content that has unfavorite icon and onclick function)

here my html for the  tag, it display base on if it is favorite or not( {% %} tag is django handling it ):

```
<div class="article-category">{{ property.get_type_display }}
     <div class="bullet"></div> {{ property.publish_date|date:'d-m-Y' }}
     {% if not request.user|is_favorite:property.id %}
         <a id="mylink" href="javascript:onclickFunction()" value="{{ property.id }}">
            <i class="far fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Add to favorite"></i>
         </a>
      {% else %}
          <a id="mylink2" href="javascript:onclickFunction()" value="{{ property.id }}">
             <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Remove from favorite"></i>
          </a>
      {% endif %}
 </div>
```

And here is my jquery script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mylink').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                property_id = $(this).attr("value")
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:9999/api/add_favorite/" + property_id + "/",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {{ refresh_token }}');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.code == 200) {
                            alert('ok');
                            replace_part_1 = '<a id="mylink2" href="javascript:onclickFunction()" value="' + property_id +'"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Remove from favorite></i></a>'
                            $("#mylink").replaceWith(replace_part_1);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
            $('#mylink2').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                property_id = $(this).attr("value")
                $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: "http://localhost:9999/api/remove_favorite/" + property_id + "/",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {{ refresh_token }}');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.code == 200) {
                            alert('ok');
                            replace_part_2 = '<a id="mylink" href="javascript:onclickFunction()" value="' + property_id +'"><i class="far fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Add to favorite"></i></a>'
                            $("#mylink2").replaceWith(replace_part_2);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Now the first time i click on favorite or unfavorite it sent to the api and work, the replace html part for "#mylink2" onclick event but the "#mylink" replace doesn't include the  tag which contain the icon.

After this any clicking event after that won't work and i have to refresh the page to click it again to work. Any click event after that also return this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: onclickFunction is not defined
>       at :1:1

I'm super noob at jquery so i can't seem to find what is wrong, hope someone can help me

**EDIT:**

i changed my script to this by replace with value attribute of anchor tag:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.article-details').on('click', '#mylink', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                property_id = $(this).attr("value")
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:9999/api/add_favorite/" + property_id + "/",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {{ refresh_token }}');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.code == 200) {
                            alert('ok');
                            replace_part_1 = '<a id="mylink2" href="#" value="' + property_id +'"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Remove from favorite></i></a>'
                            $("a[value='" + property_id + "']").replaceWith(replace_part_1);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
            $('.article-details').on('click', '#mylink2', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                property_id = $(this).attr("value")
                $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: "http://localhost:9999/api/remove_favorite/" + property_id + "/",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {{ refresh_token }}');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.code == 200) {
                            alert('ok');
                            replace_part_2 = '<a id="mylink" href="#" value="' + property_id +'"><i class="far fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Add to favorite"></i></a>'
                            $("a[value='" + property_id + "']").replaceWith(replace_part_2);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

and my html to:

```
<div class="article-category">{{ property.get_type_display }}
                                <div class="bullet"></div> {{ property.publish_date|date:'d-m-Y' }}
                                {% if not request.user|is_favorite:property.id %}
                                <a id="mylink" href="#" value="{{ property.id }}">
                                    <i class="far fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Add to favorite"></i>
                                </a>
                                {% else %}
                                <a id="mylink2" href="#" value="{{ property.id }}">
                                    <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: red" title="Remove from favorite"></i>
                                </a>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
```

it worked but the onclick of #mylink when changing the html the i tag inside  still disappear(the #mylink2 onclick worked it changed the html white the  tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are facing an event delegation problem. That is, the moment your jQuery code runs, `$('#mylink2')` does not exist in the document and hence the event doesnt get binded. [Use event delegation instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements):

```
$('.article-category').on('click', '#mylink2', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   // your original click handler
});
```

`#myParentWrapper` should be an element that is consistent in your markup, preferably not `body` or `document` for performance reasons.

You can then remove the onclick attribute from your anchor - or - actually somewhere define the function that is referenced there if it should do anything other than what your jQuery code does already.

Comment: i changed both of my onclick handle to what you suggested but now whenever i click it show "Uncaught ReferenceError: onclickFunction is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1" error in the console :/

Comment: you dont need the onclick attribute at all as it seems

Comment: so what should i change my href to? since if i remove href attribute then i cant click on the <a> tag,  i tried to change to href="#" and my event.preventDefault(); doesnt work anymore and it take me to the url

Comment: you need to pass the event to the click function, in both handlers (see my updated answer).

Comment: i change to that and href="#" now when i click on it nothing happened, i also updated my post with the parent div of both <a> tag

Comment: can you post a fiddle or code example of what your current code looks like that is not working?

Comment: nvm it worked now it because my django server didnt change it in time. But the <i> class when i do the click event on #mylink2 still disappear and the DOM change on other items i guess because it's a loop so the class and id name repeat. i will try to make a jsfiddle for this

Comment: i couldnt put it on fiddle cause the <a> tag content generate dynamically and it require the font awesome css to show, also need the access token for the api. But i had almost make it worked, the click event after first click worked now, only thing that doesnt work now is the replaceWith of the #mylink click event doesnt include the <i> tag, i had put edit part in my post

Comment: maybe its due to you not closing the title attribute correctly (missing `"`) in the mylink click handler